# JAXB return null instead empty string

Tags: java, jaxb

How I can retrieve `null` value, when unmarshalling, if inside XML attribute value is empty ? Now I make inside my getters checking for `null` :

```
public String getLabel() {
    if (label.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return label;
    }
}
```

But may be exist some other, more elegant way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would null be a better option? Instead of checking if the string is null -which you will have to do to avoid NPE- after the call, check if it is empty and you're done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your XML looks more or less like this:

```
    <myElement></myElement>
```

This, unfortunately, means, that you are **passing an empty string**.

If you want to pass `null` you have two options:

1. Do not pass this tag at all (your XML should not contain `<myElement/>` tag at all).
2. Use `xsi:nil`.

If using `xsi:nil`, first you have to declare your xml element (in XSD file) as `nilable`, like this:

```
    <xsd:element name="myElement" nillable="true"/>
```

Then, to pass the `null` value inside XML do this:

```
    <myElement xsi:nil="true"/>
```

or this:

```
    <myElement xsi:nil="true"></myElement>
```

This way, JAXB knows, that you are passing `null` instead of an empty String.

Answer (score 8):

The [answer given by npe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869834/383861) is a good one, and specifying how you want `null` represented would be my recommendation as well.  To have `xsi:nil` marshalled you will want to annotate your property as (see [Binding to JSON & XML - Handling Null](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html)):

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}
```

If you don't want to change your XML representation then you could use an `XmlAdapter`:

**EmptyStringAdapter**

```
package forum10869748;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class EmptyStringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if("".equals(v)) {
            return null;
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

}
```

**Foo**

You reference an `XmlAdapter` through the use of the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.  If you would like this `XmlAdapter` applied to all Strings then you could register it at the package level (see [JAXB and Package Level XmlAdapters](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html)).

```
package forum10869748;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String label;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EmptyStringAdapter.class)
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum10869748;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum10869748/input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(foo.getLabel());
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <label></label>
</foo>
```

**Output**

```
null
```

Comment: Quite useful piece of code - as an example of what you can do with `JAXB`. But in my opinion, what you propose here,  is dangerous. Treating empty strings as nulls without any notification that nulls are possible in contract (`WSDL`, `XSD`) is a kind of monkey-patching, and it's almost certain, that someone, someday will be getting really, really frustrated debugging this. If you want to treat empty strings and nulls the same, I'd suggest using [isBlank(String) from commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @npe - I agree that specifying `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` and explicitly representing null in the XML is the best way to go (I even upvoted your answer).  I added this answer for those people how cannot change the XML representation.  I don't consider it dangerous, as long as the user is consistent with what empty elements mean.