# How to do blank check of JAXB field annotated with @XmlElement?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I have the JAXB class as follows:

```
public class Sub implements Serializable
{
    @XmlElement(name = "A")
    protected double a;
    @XmlElement(name = "B")
    protected double b;
<getter, setter>
```

Sub class is a part of another class:

```
public class Sup implements Serializable{

    @XmlElement(name = "Sub")    
    private Sub sub;
```

Now, I want to do blank check for A and B.

if I write:

```
(SupObj.getSub != null){
//BLOCK1
  if(SupObj.getSub().getA() != Double.NaN){
   //BLOCK2
   }
}
```

and input as :

```
 <Sup>
    <Sub>
    <A></A>
    <B>1.2</B>
    <Sub>
</Sup>
```

control does not go inside EITHER  BLOCK1 or BLOCK2.

Please help me out to do the black check.

Comment: Where do you `write` those two blocks?

Comment: in the client code to do the validation of the input passed through SOAP UI

Comment: operator != is not applicable for Double.NaN because it NaN is not equal itself in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<A></A>
```

This, unfortunately, means, that you are passing an empty string, not a **null**.

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869834/1427460)

Comment: Thanks BMT. I had tried the following: @XmlElement(name = "A",nillable=true)
    protected double a;      and while using it as:  (SupObj.getSub != null){
//BLOCK1
  if(new Double(SupObj.getSub().getA()).toString().equals("")){
   //BLOCK2
   }
} but still its not going to BLOCK2. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: double is primitive type, so check with if(SupObj.getSub().getA()==0)) or also check it's value in debug.

Answer (score 0):

Change `a` type from `double` to `Double`

```
@XmlElement(name = "A")
protected Double a;
```

and check if `a` is not null

```
if (SupObj.getSub() != null && SupObj.getSub().getA() != null) {
   ...
```

Comment: As OP mention that it also not go inside block1!!

Comment: 1. the type I have defined as you have suggested.@XmlElement(name = "A")
protected double a;      2. !=null check gives compiler error with double.